# Extraction of Sharepoint list data strored into list of folders to azure blob

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, sharepoint-list

I am trying to extract Sharepoint list data to Azure blob. I am able to access the data which is directly listed as view.aspx, but then the same is present in folder and subfolders I am not able to extract the same using Azure logic apps.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEwd9.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide more details around this with screenshots or code view.

Comment: Hi Ketan, I have two scenarios: 1) Where the list data is directly stored in a SharePoint list - Which I am able to extract in blob using set items. 2) The data present in folders and subfolders than the list view. This is something I am not able to extract

Answer (score 1):

For now no actions to directly extract list data to blob. And I suppose you want to export the lists attachments to blob, so you could use `Get attachment content` to implement it. The below is the work flow.

[image]

Use `Get attachments` to get attachments `Identifier`, then get the content and create the blob with `Content` and `DisplayName`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion but this is not working out. Currently, I have two scenarios: 1) Where the list data is directly stored in a SharePoint list - Which I am able to extract in blob using set items. 2) The data present in folders and subfolders than the list view. This is something I am not able to extract.  Let me know your mail-id probabaly I can explain the issues in much detail to you.

Comment: @user3142958,did this work?  it this could help you, you could mark it as the answer.

Comment: I have tried changing the SharePoint structure as well and create All Items view(that has folders and subfolders ) changed to a data extraction view and using ( Get Items in logic app and restrict by view option but not able to succeed in that as well,l

Comment: @user3142958, you mean you could extract the list data but couldn't extract the folders data? Right? If so, you could use List folder action to get all file path then use Get file content using path to get the file content.

Comment: I tried this flow : 1) Get List View and in responce body I got all list names in "Display" 2) For each Body -> If Display Name = '<List_Name>' than Get File Content - and create a blob after that . This step is failing and condition

Comment: @user3142958,  I think the problem is the Display Name = '<List_Name>', you could check the Outputs of Get List View, the DisplayName are "Use all columns (Do not limit)" and "All Items", they are not list name.

Comment: I have added one of the approaches I took an image on the question. Since I don't have any reputation here on stack overflow I am not able to enter into chat window.

Comment: @user3142958, what folder you are listing? The list attachment folder? The attachment folder displayname just the order number of the title. Or show the detail flow picture.

Comment: @user3142958, and why you want to add a condition, you are already could get the file content.

Comment: Tried that as well but getting an error that server response is not JSON.

Comment: The only issue I want to understand is why not I am able to extract the data if that lies with subfolders. Also, Can I extract the data with View directly? As in I have a SharePoint list view page that gives all data to be (View.aspx).